# How do you go about writing a program in NASM assembly (x86-64, Linux) that replaces all printable ASCII characters in a file with another character?

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

I'm trying to write up some code that takes a file and a character as arguments and scans through the file, replacing every printable ASCII character with the one provided by the user.

e.g

```
$ program.out foo.txt x
```

Will replace all printable characters in foo.txt by x (all other bytes will be left as they are [I'm also not looking at things like unicode, etc])

Code:

```
%define sys_exit 3Ch
%define sys_write 1
%define sys_read 0
%define sys_close 3
%define sys_open 2
%define sys_lseek 8

%define std_out 1
%define EOF 0
%define O_RDWR 2

%define SEEK_SET 0
%define SEEK_CUR 1
%define SEEK_END 2
%define SEEK_DATA 3
%define SEEK_HOLE 4

%define buffer_len 1

section .rodata
  endmsg db "Done!", 10
  endmsg_len equ $-endmsg

  argmsg db "2 arguments expected", 10
  argmsg_len equ $-argmsg

  openerrormsg db "An error occurred", 10
  openerrormsg_len equ $-openerrormsg

section .bss
  buffer resq buffer_len ; The character from reading / for writing into
  repchar resq 1 ; The char we get from the user

section .text

global _start
_start:
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp
  cmp qword [rbp+8], 3
  jne arg_error

  mov rax, sys_open
  mov rdi, qword [rbp+8*3] ; argv[1] = file name
  mov r10, qword [rbp+8*4] ; argv[2] = character
  mov [repchar], r10
  xor r10, r10
  mov rsi, O_RDWR
  syscall

  cmp rax, rax
  js  open_error
  mov r12, rax ; file handler into r12

reader:
  mov rax, sys_read
  mov rdi, r12
  mov rsi, buffer
  mov rdx, buffer_len
  syscall
  cmp rax, EOF
  je done
  cmp qword [buffer], 127
  jge writer ; if the character is >= 127 (last printable ASCII), jump
  mov r10, [repchar] ; to :writer, else carry on and place repchar
  mov [buffer], r10 ; in buffer

writer:
  ; First, we offset the position back by a byte
  xor r8, r8
  sub r8, 1

  mov rax, sys_lseek
  mov rdi, r12
  mov rsi, r8
  mov rdx, SEEK_CUR ; new file pointer = current - 1 (from $r8)
  syscall

  mov rax, sys_write
  mov rdi, r12
  mov rsi, buffer
  mov rdx, buffer_len
  syscall
  jmp reader

arg_error:
  mov rax, sys_write
  mov rdi, std_out
  mov rsi, argmsg
  mov rdx, argmsg_len
  syscall

  jmp exit

open_error:
  mov rax, sys_write
  mov rdi, std_out
  mov rsi, open_error
  mov rdx, openerrormsg_len
  syscall

  jmp exit

done:
  mov rax, sys_write
  mov rdi, std_out
  mov rsi, endmsg
  mov rdx, endmsg_len
  syscall
  jmp close

close:
  mov rax, sys_close
  mov rdi, r12 ; r12 has our file-handler
  syscall
  jmp exit

exit:
  pop rbp
  mov rax, sys_exit
  xor rdi, rdi
  syscall
```

But if file foo.txt contains "oooo" and I do

```
$ program.out foo.txt x
```

the contents of the file just get changed to "iooo".

I checked in GDB that I am getting the correct arguments from the user. Any ideas?

Any other pointers (e.g if I should be doing something differently, aligning, etc) are welcome too!

Thanks :)

Comment: `cmp qword [buffer], 127` checks *way* more than a single character.

Comment: Similarly, the replacement also operates on 64 bits, but that's not actually a problem, even if overkill.